# How to add a column to in-memory table in DolphinDB?

Tags: database, dolphindb

An in-memory table in DolphinDB:

```
t=table(10:0,`time`sym`bid`ofr,[TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,DOUBLE])
```

Would like to add a new column count to t, I have tried the function addColumn, it did not work.

```
addColumn(t,`count,[INT])

execution was completed with exception
Usage: addColumn(table, newColNames, newColTypes). table must be a streaming table or a dfs-based table.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the SQL update statement to add a column to an in-memory table in DolphinDB.